# NullInjectorError: No provider for CROSS_STORAGE_CLIENT in Angular jasmine test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a simple component with some API calls. When I am trying to run the unit test I am getting following error in Angular Jasmine test:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CROSS_STORAGE_CLIENT]:
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CROSS_STORAGE_CLIENT]:
        NullInjectorError: No provider for CROSS_STORAGE_CLIENT!
```

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component depends on `CROSS_STORAGE_CLIENT` injection token while the test configuration doesn't declare a provider for this token.